# Search objects for a given string

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have these objects

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    recipient: "001",
    assessment: "Apta",
    score: "2",
    ovarian: "E1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    recipient: "ABC2",
    assessment: "Apta",
    score: "2,5",
    ovarian: "E1",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    recipient: "003",
    assessment: "Refugo",
    score: "3",
    ovarian: "E1",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    recipient: "004",
    assessment: "Apta",
    score: "4",
    ovarian: "E2",
  },
];
```

And this is my code, which when it finds the correct string it returns me:

```
const searchAnimal = value => {
  setInput(value);

  JSON.parse(records).filter(item => {
    if (item.recipient === value) {
      setSearch([item]);
    }
  });
};
```

What would the logic be to return all object.recipients that start with 00?  Would a regex maybe do it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs to be in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing a little bit the logic would help:

```
let search = function (data, searchString) {
  return data.filter((item) => {
    return item.recipient.includes(searchString);
  });
};
```

By doing so will give you the object you're searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter for the objects with a recipient that starts with 00 by using:

```
const array00Animals = data.filter((animal) => animal.recipient.substr(0, 2) === '00');
```

This will return the array of objects but only id's 1, 3 and 4 from your sample data.